# Getting error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (951): x, y in R when datasets are the same size

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I'm running the function

```
ggplot(datfr, aes(x = dat1[1:951,], y = dat2[1:951,])) + 
geom_point()
```

and getting the error

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. 
Defaulting to continuous.
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (951): x, y
```

The last error I thought only came up when the x and y values of data were different sizes, but setting the filters [1:951,] should fix that, and when I use nrow on the two datasets it returns the same number of rows. What's happening here?

Comment: What's in `dat1` and `dat2` exactly? How many columns do those data.frames have? And how does that relate to `datfr`? It would be easier to help with a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This looks like a very unusual use of `ggplot`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you meant to type (no comma after 951):

```
ggplot(datfr, aes(x = dat1[1:951], y = dat2[1:951])) + 
geom_point()
```

Otherwise, you get an error about the incorrect number of dimensions.

With the edited code, I can reproduce the error about length 1 or same length of data. I'm not really sure about why you get that error, but a solution for this example is to move where you do your subsetting, e.g.,

```
ggplot(datfr[1:951,], aes(x = dat1, y = dat2)) + 
geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reproduce the full error as above using a reproducible dataset:

```
mpg_data <- as.data.frame(mpg)

ggplot(mpg_data, aes(x = mpg_data[1:10,], y = mpg_data[1:10,])) + 
  geom_point()

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (234): x, y
```

It appears you are providing a dataframe to the aesthetics of ggplot. As explained. The arguments within the `aes` function should refer to columns within the dataframe provided in the `data` argument.

Assuming you are trying to subset the dataset before plotting, it is best either doing that before you build the ggplot or within the `data` argument of the function:

```
ggplot(data = mpg_data[1:10,], aes(x = cty, y = cyl)) + 
  geom_point()
```

> I would recommend reading up about using ggplot. There are loads of online resources which are very helpful including this: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/